# How to build a settings.apk from the android source code (aosp mirror) for settings?

Tags: android, build, android-source

How to build an apk from the android Settings apk source code independently ? Is there a set of steps to follow to compile specific app from AOSP? 
[Settings APK Source](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_settings/tree/master/src/com/android/settings)

Answer (score 2):

If you only download package/apps/Settings you will not be able to compile, having said so, if you do have the whole AOSP code in your machine, proceed as follows.

You need to do in the console, (in the root directory containing AOSP code):

```
source build/envesetup
```

`lunch`  (select desired product)

And in this particular case for Settings, if you check Android.mk [here](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_settings) 
You can see this particular module is called Settings. 
So just go with:

```
mma Settings
```

With `mma` you compile Settings and the required modules. You can check other options doing `hmm`

Comment: build/envesetup - which is not part of the Settings Github source right ? Where to find those files ?

Comment: That would be in the root directory that contains the whole AOSP code. If you only download package/apps/Settings you will not be able to compile.

Comment: `If you only download package/apps/Settings you will not be able to compile` I think thats the key point of op`s problem. @Olaia you should definitely add that to your anwer.

Comment: @ted how you done? I am getting error as duplicate product attribute in strings when I run only settings app in AS.

Comment: it is important, that command "source ..." should be issued under bash. If used another shell (like tcsh), that syntax is not recognized